# How do I use 2 VLANs on 1 Guest OS (Windows 7) over Host OS (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, vlan, vmware-workstation

I have a problem to use different VLAN on 1 machine (1 PC). I use PC Dell Inc OptiPlex 9020, my network adapter is Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM.

My host OS is Windows 7 and my guest OS is Windows 7 that runs over VMware workstation Pro for first setting up, but later on I will use VMware player.

I use VMware workstation 12 pro with version 12.5.2 build-4638234.

How do I setup to use different VLAN on 1 PC (2 VLAN IDs)? I don't want both OS (guest OS and host OS can communicate). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right you can change network settings pretty simple  all what you need to do is: 
Add new network adapter for your VM at VMware-Workstation thus you will give VM unique IPv4.

You can find link below on guide that i was using for 4.5 Workstation.
https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html

Comment: I have opened that link, but i confused since my virtual network editor  at VMworkstation 12.5.2 has difference display. so i cannot follow the steps. Do you have another useful article, so actually, is it possible to implement different VLAN ID (means different network) at 1 machine (1 PC)?

Comment: Hi, i have tried to use vlan tagging by adding vlan id at network card at host OS. i can do it after updating my network adapter. but i cannot do it at my guest os (VM).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HOST PC needs to reach both VLAN's (If you are going to use both VLAN's outside the host)
2. You need to add 2 NIC's on your Guest PC
3. Create 2 differents Networks (Using Virtual Network Editor) For VMnet0 Use one IP range (192.x.x.x) for VMnet1 Use the other IP Range (172.x.x.x). Make sure to use NAT or Host Only.
4. Go to the Guest NIC Settings, Assign Network 0 to the fisrt NIC, assign Network 1 to the second NIC.

Answer (score -1):

You need a trunk port on physical port and then Set VLAN ID on a Network Adapter in VM Host with tag

Comment: Please expand your answer - what does this mean?